# WebStorm Emmet HTML making new line

Tags: html, webstorm, emmet

In WebStorm 2020.2, when typing a list of values, for example: `nav>ul>li*5`, I get everything on one line. How can I make tags appear on individual lines?

See images below if I miss something, because I can't find any information on Google.

WebStorm's Code Style for HTML:
[image: Settings HTML]

Emmet settings:
[image: Emmet Setting]

Emmet expand preview:
[image: WebStorm Emmet same line image]

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 It's my settings of WebStorm not a code. The last image is showing only the problem what i get when typing code.

Comment: Sorry, I saw code in the images and, for some reason, assumed it had something to do with the question.

Comment: can't reproduce. Please try running **Code > Reformat Code** after expanding the abbreviation - what does the formatting look like?